# How can I add an array into another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an two element array looking like this

```
headers = [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 2, y: 3}]
```

I have another three element array that looks like:

```
ans = [{r: true},{r: false},{r:true}]
```

How can I add the second array to the first row of the first array to give:

```
[{x: 1, y: 2, ans: [{r: true},{r: false},{r:true}] },{x: 2, y: 3}]
```

Note that I don't want to define ans beforehand as it could be an array or something else. Also sorry but I think my representation of the array might not be quite the correct syntax. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: "Cannot set property 'ans' of undefined" is different than "ans is undefined". Which one of these errors is raised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
var headers = [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 2, y: 3}];
var ans = [{r: true},{r: false},{r:true}];

// define what you want the newly added property to be called
var collectionName = "ans";

// assign it only to the first item in the headers array
headers[0][collectionName] = ans;

// here are your results
console.log(JSON.stringify(headers));
```

here is a working fiddle that will output the array for you to look at in an output div

http://jsfiddle.net/9KR2P/

Comment: This still gave me: Cannot set property 'ans' of undefined

Comment: @SamanthaJ take a look at the working fiddle link which I've added in an edit.

Comment: Thanks. I will look at this now. I am having some trouble getting internet now. Did you see the other answer and fiddle. It's different from yours. Just wonder which is best. Right now I cannot get fiddle to come up but hopefully soon.

Comment: its different because its using dot notation to reference the property, which is good - my example uses [] to reference the property so that we can change the property name of "ans" in the target object to whatever you want it to be.  I just put in more code to illustrate that really.

Answer (score 7):

You actually want to add another property to an element in an array. You can do it like this

```
 headers[0].ans = ans;
```

Comment: Sorry for the repeated same comment but headers[0] is an object with fields. When I try the above it says "ans is undefined".

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign your property to your object : `headers[0].ans = ans`

Comment: I tried this but headers[0] is an object with fields. When I try the above it says "ans is undefined".

Answer (score 0):

```
var headers = [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 2, y: 3}],
    ans = [{r: true},{r: false},{r:true}];

headers[0].ans = ans;
```

Comment: Jon - I tried this but headers[0] is an object with fields. When I try the above it says "ans is undefined".