# How can I make an array of object in my function parameter call a function for each object?

Tags: javascript

I created the following `checkGrid` function which takes a count and then another two parameters. It's a solution which hardcodes in the selectOption calls and is not very flexible:

```
checkGrid = function(expectCount, typeParam, selectParam) {

   it('Check', function () {
      selectOption('examTypeSelect', typeParam).click();
      selectOption('examStatusSelect', selectParam).click();
    });

}
checkGrid(10, '*', '*');
```

Now I would like to make this more flexible so that it accepts arguments for any number of selectOption functions. So I was thinking of something that I could call like this. HEre what I would need is for the `checkGrid` function to call the `selectOption` three times:

```
checkGrid(10, [{'examTypeSelect','*'}
               {'examStatusSelect', '*'},
               {'abcSelect','29'}]);
```

How could I take an array object that's the second parameter for checkGrid and make it so that it calls any number of
`selectOption` functions depending on how many elements there are in the array?

Comment: Naturally, you'd receive the Array as an argument, and use a `for` loop.

Comment: ...but your object syntax is invalid. [Eloquent JavaScript, Chapter 4, Data structures: Objects and Arrays](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) Though based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977623/how-can-i-add-an-array-into-another-array-in-javascript), you already know proper object initializer syntax, so I'm not sure why you're not using it in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a loop over the array and [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call each function with a variable number of arguments.

```
checkGrid = function(expectCount, stuff) {
    it('Check', function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; ++i) {
            selectOption.apply(this, stuff[i]).click();
        }
    });
}
```

You would call this not with your proposed syntax (which is invalid), but like

```
checkGrid(10, [
                ['examTypeSelect','*'],
                ['examStatusSelect', '*'],
                ['abcSelect','29','and','perhaps','more','parameters']
              ]
          );
```

Finally, it's unclear what `expectCount` is supposed to do but I left it there because your original code presumably does *something* with it.

Comment: @cookiemonster: I wouldn't change the value of `this` inside the body of `selectOption`.

Comment: thanks. I did not know about the need for an apply. As far as the syntax in my call goes. Is that syntax correct as a way to call the function. Yes you are correct about expectCount. That's needed but I didn't include that code so I could make it a simpler question. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong, though the proper `this` would actually be the default since the original code doesn't pass the enclosed `this`.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: `{'examTypeSelect','*'}` etc is incorrect syntax, period.

Comment: @SamanthaJ: You should be aware that you don't really need `.apply()` here to do what you want, as long as you know each call will have 2 arguments. `selectOption(stuff[0], stuff[1]);`. Also, you don't need an Array of Arrays (or Objects). You can pass as many objects as you want to `checkGrid`, and then loop the `arguments` object starting at index `1`. This way you're using `checkGrid` as a *variadic* function, meaning the number of arguments it receives is determined when invoked.

Comment: @Jon - Thanks Jon for your help. No wonder you have 188K points. Hope you can get to 200K soon.